# Yii: CGridView Columns Totals

Tags: yii, cgridview

Please help!

I need to total three columns (Budget, Release and Expenditure) under header in CGridView as shown below

| Fund | Budget   | Release  | Expenditure|

### |      | Total:30 | Total:15 | Total: 8   |

### | A    | 10       | 5        | 3          |

### | B    | 20       | 10       | 5          |

Comment: I think you can do that via jquery. give an ID to your grid and then calculate total on document.ready. because CGridView does not have this feature. or you can use other tools like JqGrid plugin

Comment: Thx dear but i am not proficient in jquery.

Comment: I able to sum the columns in footer but not in header.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by inheriting CGridView and overriding the `renderTableHeader` function.
1st. Make your grid:

```
<?php

Yii::import('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView');

    class CGridViewWithTotals extends CGridView
    {
        public function renderTableHeader()
                {
                        if(!$this->hideHeader)
                        {
                                echo "<thead>\n";

                                if($this->filterPosition===self::FILTER_POS_HEADER)
                                        $this->renderFilter();

                                echo "<tr>\n";
                                foreach($this->columns as $column)
                                        $column->renderHeaderCell();
                                echo "</tr>\n";

                                if($this->filterPosition===self::FILTER_POS_BODY)
                                        $this->renderFilter();

                                if($this->getHasFooter())
                                {
                                        echo "<tr>\n";
                                        foreach($this->columns as $column)
                                                $column->renderFooterCell();
                                        echo "</tr>\n";
                                }

                                echo "</thead>\n";
                        }
                        else if($this->filter!==null && ($this->filterPosition===self::FILTER_POS_HEADER || $this->filterPosition===self::FILTER_POS_BODY))
                        {
                                echo "<thead>\n";
                                $this->renderFilter();
                                echo "</thead>\n";
                        }
                }
    }
```

To prevent footer from rendering(if you dont need it), override `CGridView::renderTableFooter()`

2nd. Use your new grid as always:

```
<?php

$this->widget('CGridViewWithTotals', array(
        'id'=>'my-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'emptyText'=>'No items found.',
        'ajaxUpdate'=>false,
        'columns'=>array(
                array(
                        'name'=>'field1',
                        'footer'=>$total,
                ),
        ),
));

?>
```